# How can I determinate the bases for the most simple representation of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Imagine a linear transformation $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with the ordered standard basis:
$B = (\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix})$ and 
$C = (\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix})$. The transformation is defined by $M^B_C (\Phi) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$

Lets define some other basis:

$D = (\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 3 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 7 \\ 1 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix})$ and $E = (\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix})$

In this case you get this transformation matrix:

$M^D_E (\Phi) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
110 & 156 &  93 & 195 \\ 
10  & 16  &   3 &  15 \\ 
-50 & -72 & -39 & -87 
\end{pmatrix}$

If you have $M^D_E(\Phi)$ given and you want to find the two Basis B and C so that the linear transformation $M^B_C(\Phi)$ is as simple as possible. How would you do that?
(simple means as many zeros as possible)

I guess one step could be to determine the null space.
$\left \{ \begin{pmatrix}-39\\ 15\\ 0\\ 10\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-51\\ 30\\ 10\\ 0\end{pmatrix} \right \}$

Comment: Pick a basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ for the domain and complete some linearly independent subset of $\Phi e_1, \Phi e_2, \Phi e_3, \Phi e_4$ to a basis of the range...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which gives orthonormal bases in the domain and in the codomain with respect to which the linear transformation is given by a diagonal matrix.

Comment: I can get these with Wolfram|Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD+%7B%7B110%2C+156%2C+93%2C+195%7D%2C%7B10%2C+16%2C+3%2C+15%7D%2C%7B-50%2C+-72%2C+-39%2C+-87%7D%7D - so $\Sigma$ would be my new transformation matrix and U and V would be the new basis? Is there a way to get a representation with integers only?

Comment: @moose, no, because $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices. But you can do so if you accept an scalar multiple of an integer matrix. Take for instance the standard basis in $\mathbb R^2$ rotated 45 degrees or $\{(3,4), (-4,3)\}$ normalized. Of course, in higher dimension it's not so easy but on the other hand you have more room.